# How can we increase the number of visits/day?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Every time I check our [report card](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration) we are around 200  visits a day.  With 500 being the needs work low score.  At 40 days old we seem to be doing well at the other indicators.

There is no doubt in my mind that Space Exploration asks and answers questions critical to the future of humanity. From this it follows that the site will pass Beta, and become a resource for the foreseeable future.

If we continue to ask and answer good questions, is that enough and time will bring more visitors, or is there something we as a community are not addressing?

Answer (score 5):

Short of promotion, we are doing it all right. Content is what draws visitors in, and Google is certainly indexing our content.

According to SE, 90% of our traffic should eventually come from search engines. I'd need a mod to verify this, but it seems that we are already getting views from search engines - I'm sure that the community itself isn't generating all of them.

One thing we should be doing is promoting the site on various spacey forums (not spamming!), but ultimately, we just need to focus on building the site.

If we build it, page views will come :)